# Individual volume controls to differents sounds

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple app that have various sounds and every sound (could be wav or mp3) have diferents volume controls but I don´t know where start :S

I've been searching for the answer or similar answer but not exceed.

I will apreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize separate MediaPlayer objects. Use setVolume to control their volumes.

For more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html